# Arrow Keys in Car Game

Tags: javascript

```js
let score = document.querySelector('.score');
let startScreen = document.querySelector('.startScreen');
let gameArea = document.querySelector('.gameArea');
let startGame = document.querySelector('#startGame');

let keys = {
  ArrowUp: false,
  ArrowLeft: false,
  ArrowRight: false,
  ArrowDown: false
}

let player = {
  speed: 5
};

startGame.addEventListener('click', start)

console.log(gameArea);
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);

function keyDown(e) {
  keys[e.key] = true;
  e.preventDefault();
  //console.log(e.key);
  //
  console.log(keys);
}

function keyUp(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.key] = false;

  console.log(e.key);
  console.log(keys);
}

function gamePlay() {
  //   console.log('now play the game');

  let keys = {
    ArrowUp: false,
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
    ArrowDown: false
  }

  if (keys.ArrowUp) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowDown) {
    player.y += 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowLeft) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowRight) {
    player.x += 5;
  }

  car.style.top = player.y + "px";

  car.style.left = player.x + "px";

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gamePlay)

}

function start() {

  let car = document.createElement('div');
  car.setAttribute('class', 'car')

  gameArea.appendChild(car);

  gameArea.classList.remove('hide');
  startScreen.classList.add('hide');

  player.start = true;

  player.y = car.offsetTop;
  player.x = car.offsetLeft;

  console.log(car.offsetTop);

  car.style.top = player.y + "px";

  car.style.left = player.x + "px";

  console.log(car)
}

let car = document.querySelector('.car');
```

```css
.car {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 120px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Car Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="carGame">
    <div class="score">
    </div>
    <div class="startScreen">
      <p>

        Arrow keys to move <br> If you hit another car you will lose.

        <button id="startGame">Start Game</button>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="gameArea hide"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am creating a javascript car Game but I am trying to move my car by arrow keys but it is not moving.
Please  Tell me what is mistake in my code and I want that when I press arrow keys it moves left right up down please check the mistake in my code

Comment: Please anyone help me

Comment: Your `keydown` and `keyup` event listeners do nothing that would move the car. You should be setting the `car.style` properties in one of these events.

Comment: Can you explain me more please

Answer (score 0):

The current code makes no attempt to move the `.car` element when a key is pressed. All it does is sets an object property to `true`:

```
keys[e.key] = true;
```

I would suggest creating another function, `moveCar()`, that can be called from the `keyDown` event listener. This function will hold the positioning logic that is currently found in `gamePlay()`.

Also, when you crate the `car` element, assign it to a variable that is accessible to the whole application.

```js
let score = document.querySelector(".score");
let startScreen = document.querySelector(".startScreen");
let gameArea = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
let startGame = document.querySelector("#startGame");
let car; /* This will reference the `car` element once created */

let keys = {
  ArrowUp: false,
  ArrowLeft: false,
  ArrowRight: false,
  ArrowDown: false
};

let player = {
  speed: 5
};

startGame.addEventListener("click", start);

console.log(gameArea);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);

function keyDown(e) {
  keys[e.key] = true;
  e.preventDefault();
  //console.log(e.key);
  //
  console.log(keys);

  moveCar();
}

function keyUp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.key] = false;

  console.log(e.key);
  console.log(keys);
}

function gamePlay() {
  //   console.log('now play the game');

  let keys = {
    ArrowUp: false,
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
    ArrowDown: false
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gamePlay);
}

function start() {
  car = document.createElement("div");
  car.setAttribute("class", "car");

  gameArea.appendChild(car);

  gameArea.classList.remove("hide");
  startScreen.classList.add("hide");

  player.start = true;

  player.y = car.offsetTop;
  player.x = car.offsetLeft;

  console.log(car.offsetTop);

  car.style.top = player.y + "px";

  car.style.left = player.x + "px";

  console.log(car);
}

function moveCar() {
  if (keys.ArrowUp) {
    player.y -= 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowDown) {
    player.y += 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowLeft) {
    player.x -= 5;
  }

  if (keys.ArrowRight) {
    player.x += 5;
  }

  car.style.top = player.y + "px";

  car.style.left = player.x + "px";
}
```

```css
.car {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 120px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="carGame">
  <div class="score">
  </div>
  <div class="startScreen">
    <p>

      Arrow keys to move <br> If you hit another car you will lose.

      <button id="startGame">Start Game</button>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="gameArea hide"></div>
</div>
```